# Crystal taped to radiator?

Tags: folklore, superstition, hermeticism

I bought a house and found a crystal taped to the radiator. Anyone know why someone would want to tape a crystal to the radiator? It looks like a mountain crystal but as I'm not knowledgeable about crystals I can't say for sure.

It looks like this [one](https://nvbyk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/mountain-crystal.jpg):

[image: Crystal]

Any religions or superstitions who put mountain crystals near their radiators or something?

Comment: This may qualify as folklore...  There is some discussion of quartz crystals in medieval alchemical literature, but alas that source material is not available online so far as I know.  My guess would be either (1) they wanted to heat the crystal up to increase its powers, or (2) they were hoping the crystal would improve the functioning of the heating system.  Quartz is regarded for its "purity", being highly translucent (i.e. a physical object that interacts with light.)  Tolkien's mythology involves light being held in crystals, known as [simirils](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Silmarils)

Comment: A picture of the actual crystal would improve this question.

Comment: I'll see what i can do. I'm down with stomach flu atm so  It will take a few days before I can go out again.

Comment: I believe mountain quartz to be of milky white appearance depending on its purity and is opaque compared to the shaped and polished clear crystal that is more commercial in popular culture

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many myths surrounding crystals.  They are held by many to be capable of channelling positive energy and so promoting health and wellbeing.

Your picture looks like quartz.  Quartz in particular is said to balance the energies of the body and the building.
There are many sources online that describe the properties attributed to crystals, [this](http://crystal-information.com/encyclopedia/) and  [this](https://www.crystalvaults.com/crystal-encyclopedia/crystal-guide)  are just two.  Although bear in mind that many such websites are primarily geared to selling crystals.

It is likely that the previous owner placed quartz in the home to promote wellbeing within the house.  Given that the position within the house is not simply on a shelf would indicate that it has been chosen carefully.
The position would either have been chosen by dowsing the most auspicious place - seeking positive Earth energy by Geomancy, for example placing on a ley line -  or Feng Shui techniques would have been used.  This would have depended upon the beliefs of the person placing it.

I don't believe that the radiator is significant, it would be the position that is more important.

Comment: Is there a difference between quartz and mountain crystals or is it 2 names for the same thing? It was located near the front window on the bottom floor.

Comment: I've never heard the expression *Mountain Crystal*.  I would assume it is just a name for natural quartz.